# Heavy weight vs Light weight?

Tags: strength, muscle, bodybuilding, strength-training, training

My goal is to build muscle size. There is lot of information online which says like [Arnold](http://www.bodybuilding.com/fun/31-arnold-approved-training-tips.html) says(3rd point) you need to lift heavy to increase muscle size and there's other information as well like on this [Flex](http://www.flexonline.com/training/light-vs-heavy-weight) website you need to lift light to increase your muscle size. What should I do? Lift heavy or lift light to increase my muscle size?

Answer (score 1):

You want to increace the size of your muscles, this process is called muscle hypertrophy  and it involves an increase in size of skeletal muscle through a growth in size of its component cells.

Two factors contribute to hypertrophy: sarcoplasmic hypertrophy, which focuses more on increased muscle glycogen storage; and myofibrillar hypertrophy, which focuses more on increased myofibril size.

Generally speaking, the effects of exercise are thus:

1. 1-6 reps (>85% 1RM) of work is generally accepted/acknowledged towards building Myofibril Hypertrophy (actual muscle fiber hypertrophy). Also **increases overall strength** (which influences #2 and #3) [1]
2. 6-12 reps (70-85% 1RM) is work is generally accepted/acknowledged towards building Sarcoplasmic Hypertrophy (tissues surrounding the muscle fibers). [1]
3. 12+ reps (<70% 1RM) develops mitochondria and fatigue resistance of a muscle, particularly Type I, predominantly aerobic fibers. Also allows you to tolerate more total work capacity. Note: Lower-intensity, longer-duration aerobic exercise generally does not result in very effective tissue hypertrophy; instead, endurance athletes enhance storage of fats and carbohydrates within the muscles [2]

So matter of fact, **it is not better or worse to lift light or heavy, they just lead to slightly different outcomes**.

Based on the information above, my recommendation is to lift a wide variety of rep ranges from high intensity (which means low reps, high weight) to medium intensity (traditional 8-12 body building approach) to light intensity (endurance fiber training/fatigue resistance up in reps of 15-50 in some cases) at various times in your program.

**TL;DR:
Just lift, both light for high reps and heavy for less reps.**

*[Note, the principles behind muscle growth are still debated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk%3AMuscle_hypertrophy)*

[1] Kraemer, William J.; Zatsiorsky, Vladimir M. (2006). Science and practice of strength training. Champaign, IL: Human Kinetics. p. 50. ISBN 0-7360-5628-9.

[2] van Loon LJ, Goodpaster BH (2005). "Increased intramuscular lipid storage in the insulin-resistant and endurance-trained state". Pflügers Archiv - European Journal of Physiology 451 (5): 606–16. doi:10.1007/s00424-005-1509-0. PMID 16155759.

Comment: A good effort, though there's too much information here, which is a problem because a lot of that information is outdated, and furthermore does not actually assist the OP in answering his question, but in fact may be a cause for detriment. The recommendation at the end is solid, but the theory behind it is hazy and best left that way without mentioning the details, especially with the current situation of the literature.

Comment: I have updated with sources.

Comment: (To clarify although sarcoplasmic and myofibrillar hypertrophy are generally accepted concepts, the means of inducing one over the other are not clear. Specifically I'd hesitate to ascribe a particular rep range to mostly inducing one or another. Regarding the subject of muscle growth, all rep ranges have been shown to be beneficial, and although we don't know why exactly, literature suggests training volume is the primary driver)

Comment: I don't wish to turn this into a conversation, chat is for that. However, I think i make clear that it is a sliding scale , there is no black and white in terms of types of exercises affecting specific types of hypertrophy.

Comment: New edits make it much clearer and I agree with your conclusions, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to do both to some extent, and as always it depends on context.

### Notes on the articles linked

Firstly the Arnold article also mentions he recommends doing higher reps at a lighter weight (8-12 reps) for some exercises so the "going heavy" recommendation isn't absolute.

Secondly the VERDICT in the Flex article is an example of misconstrued conclusions. The study involved doing 4 sets of 4 on the leg extension, compared to 4 sets of around 25. 4x4 on leg extensions is useless for testing the effect of heavy weights, no one does that in real life. What we can take from this article is an indicator about the effectiveness of high rep sets on isolation movements (legs particularly) for building muscle, but we probably can't take away information on the effectiveness of heavy reps. Regardless, the SENTENCING part at the end is solid and as you can see promotes a variety of rep ranges.

So frankly the solution is to do a variety of rep ranges.

Sarcoplasmic vs Myofibrillar hypertrophy is a fuzzy area in current literature, I wouldn't bother worrying about it. What we do reliably know is that volume (how much work you do, more sets or more reps at more weight is more volume) is the primary driver of hypertrophy.

### What should I do?

Do the bulk of your muscle building work in the 8-12 rep range as it's been repeatedly shown to allow for the most work in an efficient time period in a safe manner.

Do some of your main compound lifts lower (3-8 reps) and push for strength on them.

Do some of your isolation work higher (above 12 reps to as high as you like) for the size building benefits this rep range offers too.

Always bear in mind regardless of this: none of your lifting should be "easy". Whether heavy or light you are going to want to push yourself on every set to give your body a reason to grow. If you're just coasting gym workouts you won't get anywhere. You don't need to kill yourself in the gym either, but find that balance.

Comment: Good analysis of the articles. I challenge that **volume** drives hypertrophy. Aerobic exercise (low weight, high reps) is a technique used by endurance runners to store fats and carbs in their muscles (van Loon LJ, Goodpaster BH (2005). "Increased intramuscular lipid storage in the insulin-resistant and endurance-trained state". ) Can you provide links to you literature which suggests volume is most important?

Comment: @JJosaur Study on comparing single vs multi set resistance protocols (Krieger, JW. "Single vs. multiple sets of resistance exercise for musclehypertrophy: A meta-analysis". J Strength Cond Res 24: 1150–1159, 2010). In addition, effects of higher volume on acute testosterone levels: (Kraemer et al "Endogenous anabolic hormonal and growth factor responses to heavy resistance exercise in males and females". Int J Sport Med 12: 228–235, 1991). Also relevant (Smilios et al. "Hormonal responses after various resistance exercise protocols". Med Sci Sport Exerc 35: 644–654, 2003.).

Comment: I make perhaps too strong a claim with "most important", but as a reliable tool for driving hypertrophy focusing on volume has backing from such literature as well as anecdotally from the relevant sports (bodybuilding, powerlifting, etc.). Seeing as in the field of building muscle there is a lot yet to be understood, I attempt to draw conclusions from literature whilst also applying to personal experiences as a strength trainee and that of others in related sports - i would be wary of using information pertaining to endurance athletes if the goal is not endurance.

Comment: Not overly criticising you, muscle growth is still a dark art and there is a lot of conflicting information out in the world. I hope is safe to say that we can agree, **Lifting weights and having a varied and challenging programme will build muscle**

Comment: Yes certainly, and I do agree.

Answer (score -2):

Muscle size increases when exercise causes microtears in your fibres, and your body recovers. The repair process strengthens the muscles by increasing its size.

You can microtear your muscles both ways (heavy and light), although the standard rep scheme for bodybuilding is 3x8 (heavy enough to tear effectively, and light enough that you can tear multiple times).

PPL is a popular weightlifting routine to build muscle size (https://www.google.ca/search?q=ppl+routine&oq=ppl+routine&aqs=chrome.0.0l6.2447j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Also, your body releases more anabolic hormones when you lift heavy, while it releases catabolic hormones when you lift light.

All in all, you can't go wrong with 3x8. (under 6 reps taxes more your CNS [central nervous system] than tears your muscles - for example, at 8 reps, each rep tears the muscle by 0.1%, while at 5 reps each rep tears the muscle by 0.12% (20% increase), you tear 3 x 0.8% = 2.4% with 3x8, and only 3 x 0.6% = 1.8% with 3x5).

Comment: I ... I don't even know where to begin. *smh*

Comment: Heck, its amazing how misinformed people can be.

Comment: @JJosaur Care to explain why? I don't see an issue with this post. It is in accordance with the literature and actual practices in bodybuilding.

Comment: @AlexL you too bud

Comment: Broken down by paragraph: 1. While correct, this is not the only factor in increase in muscle size. 2. volume of sarcoplasmic fluid, actin and myosin contractile proteins all contribute to the increase in size of your muscle cells; micro-tear effects have only 1 study backing up their claim with no comment to the extent of growth 3. Correct, PPL is good. 4. No evidence to back the claim. 5. I'm not even going to dignify that with my time.

Comment: Mostly agree, although regarding 1 and 2: metabolic tension, muscle damage, and metabolic stress are generally hyopthesized as the three primary factors inducing hypertrophy. The info is not wrong, and as an idea this is helpful for someone like the OP looking to gain muscle. Paragraph 4. this one is just wrong, agreed. 5. recommendations aren't bad, although reasoning behind it is garbage. I feel the author has the right ideas but is having trouble expressing what he means.

Comment: Paragraph 5 is basic physics. You can usually lift 20% more when you go down to 5 reps instead of 8. Tension increases by 20%, and suppose a linear relationship between force and microtears, then you get 20% more microtears per rep. It could also be a polynomial or logarithmic relationship (studies would have to be done to find the curve), but it's a hypothesis based on first principles of physics. So far, heuristic results (based on the history of bodybuilding) have shown ~8 reps is optimal (works for both linear and polynomial (n^2) relationship).

Comment: Here is some good evidence. I don't think anyone can disagree that Hafthor Julius Bjornsson (the mountain from game of thrones) is a weak or small-muscled man. Here is his workout: http://confitdent.com/hafthor-julius-bjornssons-workout-the-mountain-game-of-thrones/ it has a mix of high and low rep exercises.